# why do the String members of my nodes print a blank line after getting created?

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list, nodes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLINE 80

typedef struct Node{
    char *data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

int get_Line(FILE *fp, char s[], int lim);
Node* addNode(Node *front, char *data);
Node* fillList(Node *front, char *txtFile, int lim);

int main () { 
    Node *dataFront = NULL;
    dataFront = fillList(dataFront,"data.txt",MAXLINE);
    printf("%s\n",dataFront->data); //prints blank line
    return 0;
}

int get_Line(FILE *fp, char s[], int lim){
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c=getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

Node* addNode(Node *front, char *data){
    Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(front!= NULL)
        newNode->next = front; 
    front = newNode;
    return front;
}

Node* fillList(Node *front, char *txtFile, int lim){
    FILE *fp = fopen(txtFile,"r");
    char data[lim];
    while(get_Line(fp,data,lim) > 0){
        front = addNode(front, data);
        printf("%s\n",front->data); //prints the string member of Node 
                                    //front just fine
    }
    printf("%s\n",front->data); //prints blank line
    fclose(fp);
    return front;
}
```

I am creating a list of nodes that contain strings by reading lines from a text file. The text file could be anything.

I put print statements in the function fillList to help debug. In the function fillList printing front->data within the while loop works, but outside the while loop a blank line is printed. In main printing the string member gives a blank line as well. I need help fixing this. Off of my debugging get_Line and addNode works fine.

**EDIT 1:**
My text file - data.txt - contains the following text -
   [txt file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt7ox.jpg)
- My output can be seen in this jpeg:
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEnSW.jpg)

Comment: What is the output of your program? I'm not sure exactly what you mean by blank line: does it come before, after, in the middle of the data? Or is that the only thing printed? You should update the question to include the program's output.

Comment: Are you sure your file doesn;t contain two `\n` at the end? And also there are **bigger** problems in your code.

Comment: `newNode->data = strdup(data)` will fix some UB

Comment: @pm100.: `strdup()` is not in the standard C library. but yes it is implemented more often.

Comment: indeed it is not a C standard, it is a posix standard and I will wager a whole $1 that the OP's system is posix compliant. I might even go to $2

Comment: @pm100.: I didn;t deny that. But yes, that being said doesn't change the fact that `strdup()` is not in the standard C library. I used the other solution. It is as safe as `strdup` but yes I am not sure about efficieny - maybe `memcpy` will give it a boost. If possible give me a feedback on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `addNode` function:

```
newNode->data = data;
```

Here, the `data` parameter corresponds to the `data` array defined in `fillList`.  So the `data` member of each list element points back to the `data` array in `fillList`.  This means that all list elements contain the same data.  When you then leave the `while` loop, `data` contains an empty string.  And since all nodes `data` member points to the local `data` array, you get an empty string when you print `front-data`.

Even worse, when you return from `fillList`, the list elements now point to a local variable which is now out of scope.  You then invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by dereferencing that invalid pointer when you call `printf` from `main`.  The blank line you see when printing from `main` is what happens to be in that invalid memory location, and you can't depend on that beahvior to be consistent.

You can fix this by allocating a new buffer for each list element and copying the string into that buffer.  You can do both at once using `strdup`:

```
newNode->data = strdup(data);
```

Also you'll want to add code when your program exits to deallocate both the nodes in the list and the strings they contain so you don't have a memory leak.

Comment: I don't get what is happening - really. This is very very weird to have this kind of behavior from OP. OP switches once more I delete the answer.

Comment: This behavior of OP is really  strange. I will delete the answer once OP unselects. +1 for a good answer.